# Jquery slide effect speed instead of duration?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to assing a speed instead of a duration value to a JQuery slide effect, so that elements with different sizes open or close at the same speed?

```
$(this).slideUp( /* SPEED instead of DURATION */ );
```

Comment: @JoaoPaulo that value is duration, not speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works... you can multiply the height of the item by some constant:

http://jsfiddle.net/4AdRH/

```
var constant = 4;

$('#div1').slideUp($('#div1').height() * constant);
$('#div2').slideUp($('#div2').height() * constant);
```

Adjust the constant to change the speed, but it will always be relative to the height of the element being animated.